# Getting javascript error even after server sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*'

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, cross-domain, cors

The server has been modified to send the right request headers.

**Server - Response Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With
```

I'm using Spring web mvc for the server (a.foo.com), and using mvc interceptors to set the HttpResponseHeaders.

I also attempted setting the origin to the domain of the request, instead of '*'.

**Client - jQuery Code**

I'm using jQuery/AJAX - jquery 1.7.1
Here is a summary of the POST request.

```
var settings = {};
settings.url = "http://a.foo.com/api";
settings.type = 'POST';
settings.data = JSON.stringify(request);
settings.dataType = 'json';
settings.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
settings.crossDomain = true; // adding or removing this, didn't make a difference
.... (setup callbacks etc)
jQuery.ajax(settings);
```

The website - html/js is hosted on a.bar.com

**Error on Client - javascript console (testing on chrome)**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://a.foo.com/api. Origin http://a.bar.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**Question**

Is there anything else I'm missing? I would like to avoid using JSONP, mostly because I require POST support.

Thanks for any pointers, and your help.

Comment: Which server is setting those headers? `a.foo.com` or `a.bar.com`?

Comment: a.foo.com is setting it.

Comment: Everything looks right, have you verified that the Access-Control headers are coming through correctly? Can you provide a jsfiddle with real endpoints perhaps?

Comment: Did you check the response header of the response?

Comment: Does `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://a.bar.com` work (With `http`, without trailing slash)? That's how my working example looks like. Also, if you need authentication, you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the response headers set for the OPTIONS request. I was setting it for the GET/POST requests.

Following this blog helped:
http://zhentao-li.blogspot.com/2012/06/enable-cors-support-in-rest-services.html

Now when I hit the endpoint (a.foo.com/api/*)  with the request method OPTIONS/GET/POST, I get the following headers:

```
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 02:58:05 GMT  
Connection: keep-alive  
Content-Length: 0   
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS   
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1   
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800  
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8   
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

I tested this out on Chrome. I wonder if there will be issues with IE! :)
I'd like for this to work with IE9 as well, but from what I read, I shouldn't get my hopes up.

Thanks @Strelok for your suggestions. And @sth and @xdazz.